# JavaScript. Предусмотреть тот случай, если сервер API не отвечает на запрос

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно заранее предусмотреть в перехвате ошибок тот случай, если сервер не ответил на запрос. Как это оформить в виде кода?

Допустим, так перехватываются ошибки, если поиск не дал результата. Но я не знаю, как написать код, который перехватывает ошибку в случае, если сервер не ответил на запрос. Хотя бы подскажите учебный материал.

```
.catch(function() {
      alert("Ничего не найдено, попробуйте еще раз!");
});
```

Comment: А как вы собираетесь обращаться? Обычно есть встроенные отлов ошибок, тот же [then... catch...](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) в [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Напишите какой код уже есть у вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала предложу 3 варианта исторически так сложилось. Примеры взяты из [developer.mozilla.org](http://developer.mozilla.org)

1. С использованием Callback на базе  [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

   ````
    oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
    oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
    oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
    oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);

    oReq.open();

    // ...

    // состояние передачи от сервера к клиенту (загрузка)
    function updateProgress (oEvent) {
      if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
        // ...
      } else {
        // Невозможно вычислить состояние загрузки, так как размер неизвестен
      }
    }

    function transferComplete(evt) {
      alert("Загрузка завершена.");
    }

    function transferFailed(evt) {
      alert("При загрузке файла произошла ошибка.");
    }

    function transferCanceled(evt) {
      alert("Пользователь отменил загрузку.");
    }```
   ````
2. C использованием [Fetch Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch((err) => {  
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
  });
```

3. Вариант это через `try catch` в паре с `await`

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // или 'PUT'
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // данные могут быть 'строкой' или {объектом}!
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log('Успех:', JSON.stringify(json));
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Ошибка:', error);
}
```